# how to get android to treat external sd as internal sd?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, storage

I have a Galaxy SL I9003 running gingerbread that was having problems such as hang and restart, unable to receive or make calls... I found the problem was a dead internal sd card so i removed it and reflashed the ROM, now the phone works but i have no storage space and it doesn't detect my external memory(even though i can read it from recovery) so how can i get android to detect the external sd? Or even better get it to treat external sd as internal sd?

Comment: Afraid on Gingerbread there's no existing solution for that (there was an app called External2Internal for some Galaxy device, though). But besides: How did you remove the internal SD card? Unsoldered some chip? Moreover, if the external card is not even detected by your device, how do you want to use it at all?

Comment: Like you said i unsoldered it from the board, as for how to use it, somehow make the system recognize it as an internal sd card.

Comment: Hard to do if it's not recognized at all. And you cannot use that "swap tool" as there's nothing to "swap" anymore. Sorry, out of ideas. And soldering tips would have nothing to do with Android, given I had any :)